# redefine multiple conflicting preprocessor definitions globally

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have large project which contains some conflicting preprocessor function definitions for example like this:

1.h:

```
#define CONFLICTINGMACRO(a, b) {doSomething(a, b)}
```

2.h:

```
#define CONFLICTINGMACRO(a, b, c) {doSomethingElse(a, b, c)}
```

Some files import both headers but find the wrong defintion(the one that is loaded first).

I (re)define other symbols (e.g. Windows functions and types not available on Linux) of the project in a file called redefinitions.h

This file is added globally to every source file of the project via compiler flag:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -include redefinitions.h")
```

For quick and easy debugging of other functionality (I don't need the conflicting macros right now) I tried adding the following lines to redefinitions.h:

```
#ifdef CONFLICTINGMACRO
    #undef CONFLICTINGMACRO
#endif
#define CONFLICTINGMACRO(...) {}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to make a difference. My best guess is, that this has something to do with the order the *.h files are loaded.

Do you have any ideas on how I could override the macros defined in the project's different header files globally for the entire project?

Comment: Presumably you can't edit the files `1.h` and `2.h` themselves?

Comment: Unfortunately there's a whole plethora of those conflicts spread over thousands of files (don't ask why, I myself am still somewhat flabbergasted by this mess...) and editing them or even writing a script for editing would take considerable time (which, of course, is something that has to be done in the future).

Comment: I know no way to tell a compiler to ignore specific (e.g. by name) macro definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way. If we rule out editing or preprocessing the sources themselves, it is impossible to achieve it, even if we give up portability and stick around gcc. From [the reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html):

> -include file
>
> > Process file as if "#include "file"" appeared **as the first line of** the primary source file. (...)

As such, your `redefinition.h` will be included above every other headers that try to define `CONFLICTINGMACRO`. Same goes around `-D` and `-U`; any macro redefinition will follow the last seen in general. There's no preprocessor option to override such behavior.

An alternative hack would be to copy the whole file tree of all the included header files (e.g., include/ -> include_wrapper/), and then modify all files into following same content:

```cpp
#include_next __FILE__
#ifdef CONFLICTINGMACRO
    #undef CONFLICTINGMACRO
#endif
#define CONFLICTINGMACRO(...) {}
```

Then set include directories for it (include_wrapper/) before anything else. In this way, you're basically `#undef`ing the macro after every inclusion of the wrapped headers. Of course you are going to sacrifice portability since `#include_next` is quite a not-so-common preprocessor extension.

Comment: Had I only seen your answer earlier. In the mean time I started writing a pyhon sript, which edit the define statements.
Man... its not enough that there are conflicting macros, no, most of them are spread over multiple lines with the formatting following no recognizable pattern so that you can't do a simple replace...
The people who work on this code claim that it compiles fine with VisualC++. I mean, really?!
Anyway thank you, I'll try your solution, if my script takes too long to write.